# SSL certificate also on staging

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, staging

When installing a SSL on the production environment, would it be wise to also install this on a staging environment?

Especially when tacking additional costs into account of the extra SSL certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to mimic production as good as possible, so that would include a certificate.

You can do two things:
1) Buy a cheap $10 certificate
2) Create a selfsigned certificate.

The latter option will give you a message that it can't validate the certificate, but this is fine because it's only staging.

Example:
You have to set the certificates in your server: [Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/392099-creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-apache-on-linux), [Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx), [Mac](http://brianflove.com/2014/12/01/self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-mac-yosemite/)

Next, you have to install the certificate*:
[Apache](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-self-signed-certificate.html), [Nginx](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/install-self-signed-ssl-certificate-nginx-cenos-7/)

`* -` this dependents on your OS

Comment: That message that it can't validate the certificate, is that a page with a promt where you have to manually click on the button under the security notice where you accept the risks?

Comment: Yes, like this: http://blog.getpostman.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ssl_error.png?7aa172

Comment: Trying to avoid that :).

Comment: For your https connection it works perfectly fine, otherwise, you can install a cheap $10 one.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a free SSL certificate for the subdomain staging.example.com from services like Let's Encrypt.